# iphone map pins for icons replacement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, maps

I am trying to build a map based app on iphone. Can the standard pins be replaced by other similarly sized icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can. Set the image property of the [MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).